# How to twinkle the background color of any JComponent?

Tags: java, swing, colors, background, jcomponent

I'm trying to twinkle the background color of a JButton but only the 'sleep' it's working.

My code:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

  if(!empty){
  }else{
  myButton.setBackground(Color.RED);
  try {TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(200);} catch (InterruptedException e2){}
  myButton.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
  try {TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(200);} catch (InterruptedException e1) {}
  myButton.setBackground(Color.RED);
  try {TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(200);} catch (InterruptedException e1) {}
  myButton.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
  }
  }
}
```

EDIT:
Can't post the whole code, so many lines. 
The button is inside a GridBagLayout:

```
myButton= new Jbutton("Button!");
myButton.setBackground(Color.White);
myButton.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);;
myButton.setForeground(Color.black);
GridBagConstraints gbc_myButton = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc_myButton.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
gbc_myButton.gridx = 0;
gbc_myButton.gridy = 1;
gbc_myButton.gridwidth=3;
panel.add(myButton, gbc_myButton);
```

EDIT 2:
I just figure out it's not setting any color at runtime (with or without any delay/sleep).

Comment: what do you mean 'only the `sleep` is working'?

Comment: The delay works, but the color doesn't change.

Comment: a) 200 milliseconds is very short, try a longer sleep period. b) are you looping that code?

Comment: Tested with 1 sec, no difference. No, I'm not looping.

Comment: please provide all the relevant code (where in the code is the block you posted placed etc.)

Comment: Careful not to send the EDT thread into sleep. It will make the GUI unresponsive.

Comment: Don't use `sleep()`. Using a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). You're *blocking* the Event Dispatch Thread, so it can't redraw the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `javax.swing.Timer` to do animations like this.

```
final Button b = ...;
final Color[] colors = ...;
colors[0] = Color.RED;
colors[1] = Color.LIGHT_GREY;
ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
  int loop = 0;
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    loop = (loop + 1) % colors.length;
    b.setBackground(colors[loop]);
  }
}

new Timer(200, al).start();
```

NOTE: Not all Components / JComponents actually change the background through calls to setBackground

Comment: How do I retrieve the ActionListener object from my class ? Because you are creating a new one. If I do new Time(200,this) it's giving me a NullPointer in the 1st line of the actionPerformed() .

Comment: I don't understand your questions. Where are you trying to retrieve the ActionListener? What is new Time(200,this)? And if you are getting a NullPointerException on the first line of actionPerformed, this means that you haven't actually put colors into the `colors` array

Comment: I thought I had to use the ActionListener that was implementing my class. After read whole docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html I figure out it's a new ActionListener inside the actionPerformed of my class. Then I tried your code, the color is changing but the loop doesn't stop.

Comment: Rather than continually looping using modulus, you could implement to ignore future calls to actionPerformed after the first 4. Alternatively, could make the Timer `final` or a class member so you can reference it within the timer, and use Timer.stop when you want to stop the changes

Comment: OK, I think there must be something simpler, but works for now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you sleep the UI thread (via `TimeUnit...sleep(x)`), it won't be able to re-render the changes. I bet the last colour does get rendered.

You need to find an alternative way of triggering the color changes, look at timers, particularly swing timer.

Comment: (1-) Swing components  should be updated on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). So you should be using a Swing Timer, not the other timers mentioned in that link.

Comment: @camickr yes those other timers aren't suitable, thanks